# Merging shapefiles as Virtual Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

In QGIS 3.6.3 I'm trying to create a Virtual Layer obtained by merging 12 shapefiles (with the columns named and ordered in the same way) using the expression

```
SELECT *
FROM _January, _February, _March, _April, _May, _June, _July, _August, _September,
_November, _October, _December
```

but the software crashes.

If I wanted to create a Virtual Layer by taking data from a single column called `"TEST"`, how can I modify the expression? I could not find the correct form.

Comment: A little more additional information, such as type of software and what tools you are using for the merge, might help provide an answer.

Comment: thanks @kazuhito, I tried the formula (2) and it works.
I asked why when I tried it I couldn't get it to work (because I was wrong to write the command to join all the layers)
thanks again for help

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/165854)

Answer (score 2):

Like this? (not tested).

(1) Merging all fields of 12 layers

```sql
SELECT * FROM "_January"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM "_February"
UNION ALL
............. // please repeat - March to November
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM "_December"
```

(2) Merging layers, and selecting only `TEST` field

```sql
SELECT TEST, "_January".geometry FROM "_January"
UNION ALL
SELECT TEST, "_February".geometry FROM "_February"
UNION ALL
............ // please repeat  - March to November
UNION ALL
SELECT TEST, "_December.geometry" FROM "_December"
```

UPDATE (3) Using table from (2), choose only `TEST` field is *TRUE*

```sql
SELECT a.TEST, a.geometry AS geometry
FROM (
     SELECT TEST, "_January".geometry FROM "_January"
     UNION ALL
     SELECT TEST, "_February".geometry FROM "_February"
     UNION ALL
     ............ // please repeat  - March to November
     UNION ALL
     SELECT TEST, "_December".geometry FROM "_December"
) AS a
WHERE TEST = 'TRUE'
```

Comment: work, thanks!

I take advantage of it, instead I wanted to select from the TEST column the TRUE values, how can I modify the sql formula?

Comment: hi @Fabrizio How about add another filter on top of the expression written in the above  example `(2)`? I mean we can put the output of `(2)` as a table, and set `SELECT` syntax from this new table.

Comment: hi again @Fabrizio Not sure if it works, but I tried to add `(3)` which selects only if TEST field is TRUE. Let me know if I have misunderstood the request.